# Passing Parameters in Jade Link to Node Controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node.js project that has a table containing links.  Each link needs to go to the same page, `'/map'`, but pass in information to that page. I'm using Jade to create the links.

> index.jade

```
extends layout

block content 
        center      
            img(src='/images/mosaic.png')
            p 
                b Select a Block Library to view:

            div 
                table 

                    tr
                        td Description 
                        td Min Zoom Level 
                        td Max Zoom Level 
                        td Path on Disk 
                        td Try it out! 


                    each val, index in configs
                        tr
                            td= val.desc
                            td= val.min_zoom
                            td= val.max_zoom 
                            td= val.tile_directory
                            td
                                a(href='/map')
                                    img(src='/images/chicklet.jpg')
```

I would like the link to pass information from `val` to the controller.

---

> app.js

```
app.get('/map', function(req, res){
    res.render('view', {type: "block", name: "", latitude: "", longitude: "", zoom: ""}); 
});
```

I want to fill in the name, latitude, longitude, and zoom information with the information passed from `index.jade`.  How would I pass this information and retrieve it in the controller?

Comment: Read the documentation http://jade-lang.com/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the client side, you can add those information to the url query, such as it looks like 
`/map?name=testname?latitude=123&longitude=123&zoom=abc`

And in the expressJS, you can read them in the route handler.

```
app.get('/map', function(req, res){
    res.render('view', {type: "block", name: req.query.name, latitude: , longitude: req.query.longitude, zoom: req.query.zoom}); 
});
```